# Any significant differences in Java number "casting"

Tags: java

Is there any significant difference in casting a literal number vs. using a suffix on the literal number?

To illustrate...

```
doSomethingWithLong(2L); //vs...
doSomethingWithLong((long) 2);
```

To clarify: Let's assume that the code still compiles with the literal value that is used.

Comment: Sometimes you need to do some test before posting a question.

Comment: Regarding your clarification: There is no difference in the bytecode produced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first one, you are using `long` literal. In the second one you are casting an `integer` literal to a `long`.

They won't behave the same, if the value is too big to be stored in an `int` type. For e.g., the 2<sup>nd</sup> code won't compile for value greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, or less than `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

You should also be very careful while performing arithmetics with integer literals. You might get unexpected result, when the result of the arithmetic operation, goes out of range. For e.g:

```
System.out.println(123456 * 123456); // Will print `-1938485248`
```

---

**Related Post:**

- [Why do these two multiplication operations give different results?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12758338/1679863)
- [Casting an int into a long](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14632893/1679863)

---

> Let's assume that the code still compiles with the literal value that is used.

Assuming that you have literals for which the code compiles, there is no difference in bytecode. The above two invocations generates the same bytecode as you can see below. You can use `javap -c YourClass` command to see the bytecode:

```
0: ldc2_w        #2                  // long 2l
3: invokestatic  #4                  // Method doSomethingWithLong:(J)V
6: ldc2_w        #2                  // long 2l
9: invokestatic  #4                  // Method doSomethingWithLong:(J)V
```

Answer (score 8):

You wouldn't be able to compile

```
 doSomethingWithLong((long) 222222222222222222); 
 // The literal 222222222222222222 of type int is out of range
```

Because `222222222222222222` doesn't fit in `int`.

You can read about the primitive data types in [this official Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

> The int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -2,147,483,648 and a maximum value of 2,147,483,647
>   (inclusive).
>
> The long data type is a 64-bit signed two's complement integer. It has
>   a minimum value of -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and a maximum value of
>   9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive).

*Let's assume that the code still compiles with the literal value that is used.*

They are equivalent, see Rohit's byte code answer.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from certain things not compiling, you can get unexpected results if you are not careful -
5d/2d returns 2.5
5/2 returns 2